# Issue with Deploying an app in IIS 7.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, deployment, iis-7.5

I am trying to deploy an app on IIS7.0

I developed the app in 4.0 (Just a web app not MVC or anything)

These are the steps I followed

---

1.Select Application pools -> Create New ->TestApp--> Select the framework version to 4.0

1. Sites -> Add web Sites -> SiteName ->TestApp -->Choose the TestApp Application Pool
2. Select the Physical Path
3. If I leave the Host Name Empty and click on Ok

when I go to the website and manage application ->Browse I am seeing the App as localhost (Very Well)

But When I enter the host name as Testapp.Domainname.com It is not working what am I doing wrong??

Comment: Do you have a DNS setup to point Testapp.Domainname.com to your server?

Comment: I don't really know much :( How can I check that

Answer (score 0):

You need to have that domain configured in DNS server you're using. If you want to have the app accessible under this URL from the internet, you need to go to one of the domains resellers, buy the domain name and configure it to point to your IIS server.

For development, you probably want to set up DNS name locally, for your machine only - you have to specify this domain name in your [hosts file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29) than:

```
127.0.0.1  testapp.domainname.com
```

Comment: I am a intern and we do have a domain name (My company's) So now tell me how can I configure it on my IIS? I have other sites working well with in that domain.

Comment: To run it on IIS on your machine, you'll need to have your corporate DNS pointing to your machine and you probably don't want to have it configured like that. Use second advice and edit your own hosts file.